# Multiple navbars REACTJS

Tags: reactjs, dom

I have three diferent navbars for my project:

- If the user is logged in
- One for the homepage
- One for other pages

The difference is that on the home page I don't want to see login and register links in the nav bar beacuse i have buttons for that on the page if the user is not logged in. And i have another navbar for other pages because i wnat the user to be able to access the view and add new entry from every page. The question is: do i make multiple files like: `navbar.jsx`, `navbarNotHome.jsx`, `navbarHome.jsx`, or is there any way to export more than one class from the same `jsx` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would make a seperate file for each navbar, but that is a matter of taste. It is indeed possible to export multiple classes from the same jsx file.

For only exporting a singular class you would normally export it as:

```
export default ClassDefault;
```

And then import it as:

```
import ClassDefault from 'yourpath';
```

For multiple you can export them bundled together as an object like so (you don't even have to export a class by default if you don't want to):

```
export {
    ClassOne,
    ClassTwo,
    ClassThree
};

export default ClassDefault;
```

You can then import each of these classes as follows:

```
import ClassDefault, { ClassOne, ClassTwo, ClassThree } from 'yourpath';
```

Or if you only want ClassTwo:

```
import { ClassTwo } from 'yourpath';
```